# check if a string in the address bar matches an li id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if my address has any words that matches word in my li id:

```
<ul>
   <li id="filter-myId" class="noSelected">Text</li>
</ul>
```

url address example to check:

http://www_link.com/D=.myId

But on the window address bar it'd only display "myId" without "filter-", so I guess I need to check if whatever is after "filter-" matches a string which appears on the windows address. If so, the li would get a class "selected"

Help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: tried few things such as indexOf and string replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, though currently untested, something along the lines of:

```
var string = document.location.href.split('=')[1];

if ($('li[id*="' + string + '"]').length){
    $('li[id*="' + string + '"]').addClass('selected');
}
```

To restrict the search to those `li` elements that have the `filter-` prefix:

```
var string = document.location.href.split('=')[1];

if ($('li[id^="filter-"][id*="' + string + '"]').length){
    $('li[id^="filter-"][id*="' + string + '"]').addClass('selected');
}
```

References:

- [Attribute-contains (`[attribute*="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).
- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: i could then just use $(this).addClass("selected"); once found it?

Comment: This wouldn't restrict it to just the elements with a `filter-` prefix.

Comment: You couldn't use `$(this)`, because there's no `this` element within the context of the `if`, you could use the same selector, though, in place of the `$(this)`.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, but I hadn't actually realise that was a requirement. I'll update the answer to include that as an option.

Comment: Still curious why you would do a compound selector instead of basic string concatenation to get the exact `id`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the URL somehow. I'm leaving that part out, but assuming it is placed in an object called `url`.

**Javascript**

```
if (elem = document.getElementById('filter-' + url['D'])) {
  // exists
  elem.className += ' selected';
}
```

**jQuery**

```
elem = $('#filter-' + url['D']);
if (elem.length) {
  // exists
  elem.addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: what's "D" tho? the string in the address could be any and I have many different ids. I need a not pre-difined solution rather a dynamic one

Comment: So make it dynamic based on my example :)